# Export as CSV and Excel in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, export-to-excel, export-to-csv

I have a list of email-ids stored in a variabe ( Say `@emails` ). This list is being generated in a controller inside an action. This action is specifically made for this purpose. Now I want to enable the user to download this list other than viewing it as HTML. I am unable to find a way of doing it. (Also there is no model associated with emails so I think the approach described in Railscasts won't work here)

Answer (score 1):

I've been using the axlsx_rails gem for this. Easy to install and to use.

https://github.com/randym/axlsx

Answer (score 0):

for that follow these links:-

http://railscasts.com/episodes/362-exporting-csv-and-excel